# I tried to make a find max/min function and it does not work properly while not giving back any errors (C language)

Tags: c

Just as the title said, I tried to make a function that finds max/min grades from a list of grade structs by creating a new variables that stores highest/lowest grades and then compare it with each instance in an array of struct to find the desired result. However, my function does not work as intended and it returns both max grade for both function min and max

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student{
    char name[50], studentID[50];
    float grade;
} std[30];

int n;

void add(){
    
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("\nAdd the students details no%d", i+1);
        printf("\n**********************************");
        printf("\nStudent's name: ");
        scanf(" %s", &std[i].name);
        getchar();
        printf("\nStudent's ID: ");
        scanf(" %s", &std[i].studentID);
        getchar();
        printf("\nStudent's grade: ");
        scanf(" %f", &std[i].grade);
        getchar();
        system("cls");
    }
}

void displayRecords(){
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        printf("\n**************************");
        printf("\nStudent's name: %s", std[i].name);
        printf("\nStudent's ID: %s", std[i].studentID);
        printf("\nStudent's grade: %.2f", std[i].grade);
        printf("\n**************************\n");
    }
    getch();
}

float max(){
    float maxGrade = std[0].grade;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(std[i].grade > maxGrade);
        maxGrade = std[i].grade;
        
    }
    printf("Max grade: %.2f", maxGrade); 
    getch();
    return maxGrade;
}

float min(){
    float minGrade = std[0].grade;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(std[i].grade < minGrade);
        minGrade = std[i].grade;
        
    }
    printf("Min grade: %.2f", minGrade);
    getch(); 
    return minGrade;
}

int main() {
    while(1){
    int a;
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\t\t\t----------Welcome to SMS----------");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t\tPlease choose your action");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t1.Create new record");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t2.View a record");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t3.Find max grade");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t4.Find min grade");
        printf("\n\t\t\t\t5.Exit");
        printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\tYour choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
    
    switch(a){
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            printf("Please enter the amount of records you want to add <1-30>: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            add(n);
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            displayRecords(n);
            break;
        case 3:
            system("cls");
            max(n);
            break;
        case 4:
            system("cls");
            min(n);
            break;
        case 5:
            system("cls");
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tSee you again next time!");
            getch();
            return 0;
        default:
            system("cls");
            printf("Error! Please enter again");
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 4... Assign the return of `min(n);` and `max(n);` so the returned `max` and `min` isn't simply discarded. The space at the beginning of `" %s"` and `" %f"` is completely unnecessary. The only conversion specifiers that do NOT discard leading whitespace are `"%c"`, `"%[..]"` and `"%n"`  (use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` and you don't need to remember each pitfall that `scanf()` has for you.

Answer (score 2):

OP's `if()` ends too early for min and max.

```
    // Bad   
    if(std[i].grade < minGrade);
    minGrade = std[i].grade;

    // Should be
    if(std[i].grade < minGrade)
    minGrade = std[i].grade;
```

Look carefully.

Best to enable all compiler warnings to save you and us time.